# How to run parallel controllers using weighted switch controller

Tags: jmeter

After user logs in, need to execute any 1 of 3 different set of parallel requests, on top of it  all users should wait and execute parallel requests at one go.

I have tried Parallel controller adding to Transaction controller ,and added them as children of Weighted switch controller with Synchronization timer. But it is not executing with expected weightages.

Please help with right approach/structure of test plan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with the Weighted Switch Controller plugin, you can report it either via [JMeter Plugins support forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins) or in case you're a BlazeMeter Customer do it via [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

In the mean time you can use "normal" [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) and come up with the desired "weights" distribution by either using [CSV file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or a function like [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)